# we are having MySite in our SP 2016. We have 2 content db now but the size limit was exhausted

Tags: sharepoint-server, mysites

we are having MySite in our SP 2016. We have 2 content db, but the size limit was exhausted. So we need to create new content DB and we have to make them sync.

Mysites will be automatically created and it should acquire the space in new content db.

Can any one please provide the steps s for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below steps:

1. Create a new content database for My Sites using SharePoint Central Administration or PowerShell. Make sure to note the name of the new content database.
2. Set the new content database as the default content database for My Sites. To do this, go to SharePoint Central Administration > Application Management > Manage service applications. Click on the User Profile Service Application. Click on Manage User Profile > Manage My Site Settings. Under the "Preferred Search Center" section, select the new content database from the dropdown list and click OK.
3. Configure the User Profile Service Application to use the new content database for My Sites. To do this, go to SharePoint Central Administration > Application Management > Manage service applications. Click on the User Profile Service Application. Click on Manage User Profile > Configure Synchronization Settings. Under the "My Site Settings" section, select the new content database from the dropdown list and click OK.
4. Run a full User Profile Synchronization to ensure that all existing My Sites are moved to the new content database. To do this, go to SharePoint Central Administration > Application Management > Manage service applications. Click on the User Profile Service Application. Click on Start Profile Synchronization and select "Full Synchronization".
5. Verify that new My Sites are being created in the new content database. To do this, create a new My Site and check which content database it is being created in.